# Android AIDL support "short" type?

Tags: android, aidl

Does AIDL support short type ?

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

It said "All primitive types in the Java programming language (such as int, long, char, boolean, and so on)"

But it seems cannot use short in AIDL.

thanks !

Comment: Out of interest, why do you require a short? Will a char, byte[] or int not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not :/ so use an int and cast it back to short afterwards